ThemeProvider from Styled-components not working in storybook (Next.js 13)
I'm currently working on a Next.js website and using styled-components along with Storybook. While I've configured everything to work well with Storybook, I've encountered an issue with the ThemeProvider.
Previously, everything was functioning correctly, but after migrating the project from Create React App (CRA) to Next.js 13, it seems like the ThemeProvider isn't cooperating as expected.
can you guys please help me with this?
this is .storybook/main.ts.
import * as path from 'path';
import type { StorybookConfig } from '@storybook/nextjs';

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: [
    '../stories/**/*.mdx',
    '../stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)',
  ],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-onboarding',
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@chromatic-com/storybook',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions',
  ],
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/nextjs',
    options: {
      image: {
        loading: 'eager',
      },
      nextConfigPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../next.config.js'),
    },
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: 'tag',
  },
  staticDirs: ['../public'],
};
export default config;

and this is .storybook/preview.ts.
import type { Preview } from '@storybook/react';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import { theme } from '../styles/theme';
import { GlobalStyles } from '../styles/GlobalStyles';
import { withThemeFromJSXProvider } from '@storybook/addon-styling';

const preview: Preview = {
  parameters: {
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/i,
      },
    },
    nextjs: {
      appDirectory: true,
    },
  },
};

export default preview;

export const decorators = [
  withThemeFromJSXProvider({
    themes: { theme },
    Provider: ThemeProvider,
    GlobalStyles,
  }),
];

I've tried everything..


import type { Preview } from '@storybook/react';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import { theme } from '../styles/theme';
import { GlobalStyles } from '../styles/GlobalStyles';
import { withThemeFromJSXProvider } from '@storybook/addon-styling';

const preview: Preview = {
  decorators: [
    (Story) => (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <GlobalStyles theme={theme} />
            <Story />
      </ThemeProvider>
    ),
  ],
  parameters: {
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/i,
      },
    },
    nextjs: {
      appDirectory: true,
    },
  },
};

export default preview;





worked for me: https://github.com/morewings/storybook-addon-theme-provider
preview.ts:
 decorators: [
    withThemeProvider(Provider),
    ///...
  ],

Provider.tsx:
export const Provider = <TTheme,>({
  children,
  theme,
}: {
  children?: ReactNode
  theme?: TTheme
}) => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme as DefaultTheme}>
      <GlobalStyles />
      {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

